# APScheduler ID not found?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

Can date scheduled jobs have IDS? I don't know what I am doing wrong but whenever I run this code, I get the error:

> apscheduler.jobstores.base.JobLookupError: 'No job by the id of item_last_run was found'

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(timezone="America/New_York")

message = "test"
def display_message():
    print(message)
    scheduler.remove_job('item_last_run')

scheduler_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds = 3 )

print(f"\n\n***********SCHEDULED JOB FOR {scheduler_date}")
scheduler.add_job(display_message, 'date', run_date=scheduler_date, id='item_last_run')
scheduler.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a `time.sleep()` before calling the `remove_job()` function. I had the same issue and added a `time.sleep(1)` before it actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Maybe adding a listener is a better solution.

```
scheduler.add_listener(job_listener, EVENT_JOB_ERROR| EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED)
```

and modify job in listener

```
def job_listener(Event):
    job = scheduler.get_job(Event.job_id)
    if Event.job_id is not None and Event.job_id == Your Job Id:
        job.reschedule(trigger='interval', seconds=10)
```